# NSAttributedString default color/font etc

Tags: nsattributedstring

I'm using `drawGlyphsForGlyphRange` to render an `NSAttributedString` (in `NSView` `drawRect`)

Is there any way to default the color/font etc of an `NSAttributedString`? Clearly I could set those values specifically for a given range - but that will then override any specific settings in the string. Got the feeling I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how `NSAttributedStrings` should be used!!

Thanks

Comment: Really helpful Jay - if you don't know the answer or don't understand the question then best bet is to ignore it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default font for NSAttributedString objects is Helvetica 12-point on iOS and Lucida Grande (or whatever the default system font is set to) on OS X. Use `initWithString:attributes:` to create an NSAttributedString with some pre-set attributes that would initially apply to the whole string. Any attributes you will set to different ranges of your string afterwards will supplement/replace the attributes you define when you create your instance of NSAttributedString.