# UILabel attributed text not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, key-value-observing

I am having a problem updating the text on a `UILabel`. My `ViewController` changes its view property `phoneNumberString`. My view observes this property change and reacts, changing the label's attributed text. It observes using ReactiveCocoa.

```
[[RACAble(self.phoneNumberString) distinctUntilChanged]subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSString* s=(NSString*)x;
    UIFont* font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:numbersFontSize weight:UIFontWeightThin];
    NSMutableDictionary* attributesDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,NSFontAttributeName, nil];

    self.phoneNumberLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:s attributes:attributesDict];
    [self.phoneNumberLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    NSLog(@"label att text = %@\nlabel text = %@\ninput string = %@\n==",self.phoneNumberLabel.attributedText,self.phoneNumberLabel.text,x);
}];
```

It provides the following log:

```
label att text = +7 (225{
NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7a2942c0> font-family: \".SFUIDisplay-Thin\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 25.00pt";
}

label text = +7 (225
input string = +7 (225
```

I need attributed text to be located in my `UILabel`. The problem is that it provides no changes in the simulator. (Using native `[self observeValueForKeyPath...]` results in the same effect).
I've solved this problem using notifications with the same code. But I have to use KVO.

Additional information:

1. Here is my initialization code (before setting the observer):

   ```
    UILabel* phoneNumberLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];

    font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:numbersFontSize   weight:UIFontWeightThin];

    attributesDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,NSFontAttributeName, nil];

    phoneNumberLabel.attributedText=[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"+7 " attributes:attributesDict];
   ```
2. Both methods run on the main thread.
3. The `UILabel`'s frame is big enough to allocate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728466/use-multiple-font-colors-in-a-single-label-swift/27728516#27728516

Comment: Have you tried using `RACObserve` instead of `RACAble`?  I've had much greater success with that one.  Also, where are you setting up the RAC binding, viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes, i've tried. I've also tried with native observing. I set it up in initialization of the view, wich contains label

Comment: You might try setting up the RAC bindings in `-viewDidLoad` instead; it's possible that not all of the objects are fully instantiated at the point that you're trying to set up the binding.

Also, looking again at what you've posted, I don't see where `self.phoneNumberString` is actually being set; can you post that additional code as well?

Answer (score 3):

If you have used size classes in .xib to set font of label then attributed text may not work. To work it properly remove size classes from .xib file

Answer (score 1):

Try calling your method in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. For me it did the trick.
I was doing it in `viewDidLoad` and it was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing an assignment of the attribute to a range of the string. For example,

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedPhoneNumber = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:x];
[attributedPhoneNumber addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedPhoneNumber length])];
self.phoneNumberLabel.attributedText = attributedPhoneNumber;
```

Comment: This post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029222/nsattributedstring-default-color-font-etc seems to indicate that, initially, if you don't specify a range, then `initWithString:attributes:` would use a default range of the whole string, which confirms my experience with it.  However, I haven't been able to find anything in Apple's docs to corroborate.

Comment: I didn't know that.  I went based on code that I had used successfully.  Thanks for the info!